# Formatting readme.txt file for WordPress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, markdown

I published a free plugin to WordPress repository and I could not format readme.txt file to display ordered list in the correct way, all the list items appears on the same line.

please check the description on this link:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-cloaker/

I tried to separate the list items by comma as this article says 
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/improve-wordpress-plugins-readme-txt/
but it does not work

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's markdown...You need a blank line between your initial content and the ordered list:

```
Here are some Features of **WP Cloaker** plugin:

1. Hide, shorten your links.
2. Custom redirection type: 301,302,303,307 and Javascript redirection.
3. Categorize your links.
4. Custom permalinks e.g : www.yoursite.com/visit/link-category-slug/link-slug.
5. Track links clicks, each time a visitor click on any link, the plugin will store the visitor information like (IP address, click date/time, Country, etc..).
6. You can add third party tracking code.
```

As the file has [currently been written](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/wp-cloaker/trunk/README.txt#L13), that blank line does not exist.